# int can't be converted to boolean?

Tags: java

This is part of my homework for my Computer Science class. I am a new programmer and I am stuck on the check alarm method. It is supposed to check to see if aHours is equal hours and aMinutes is equal to minutes and aSeconds equal to seconds. It keeps giving me an error message saying "bad operand types for binary operators '=='  first type: int   second type: NumberDisplay"

Here is the code:

```
/**
 * The ClockDisplay class implements a digital clock display for a
 * European-style 24 hour clock. The clock shows hours and minutes. The 
 * range of the clock is 00:00 (midnight) to 23:59 (one minute before 
 * midnight).
 * 
 * The clock display receives "ticks" (via the timeTick method) every minute
 * and reacts by incrementing the display. This is done in the usual clock
 * fashion: the hour increments when the minutes roll over to zero.
 * 
 * @author Michael Kölling and David J. Barnes
 * @version 2016.02.29
 */
public class ClockDisplay
{
    private NumberDisplay hours;
    private NumberDisplay minutes;
    private NumberDisplay seconds;
    private String displayString;    // simulates the actual display
    private int aHours;
    private int aMinutes;
    private int aSeconds;
    private boolean isSet;

    /**
     * Constructor for ClockDisplay objects. This constructor 
     * creates a new clock set at 00:00.
     */
    public ClockDisplay()
    {
        hours = new NumberDisplay(24);
        minutes = new NumberDisplay(60);
        seconds = new NumberDisplay(60);
        updateDisplay();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for ClockDisplay objects. This constructor
     * creates a new clock set at the time specified by the 
     * parameters.
     */
    public ClockDisplay(int hour, int minute, int second)
    {
        hours = new NumberDisplay(24);
        minutes = new NumberDisplay(60);
        seconds = new NumberDisplay(60);
        setTime(hour, minute, second);
    }

    /**
     * This method should get called once every minute - it makes
     * the clock display go one minute forward.
     */
    public void timeTick()
    {
        minutes.increment();
        if(minutes.getValue() == 0) {  // it just rolled over!
            hours.increment();
        }
        updateDisplay();
    }

    /**
     * Set the time of the display to the specified hour and
     * minute.
     */
    public void setTime(int hour, int minute, int second)
    {
        hours.setValue(hour);
        minutes.setValue(minute);
        seconds.setValue(second);
        updateDisplay();
    }

    /**
     * Return the current time of this display in the format HH:MM.
     */
    public String getTime()
    {
        return displayString;
    }

    /**
     * Update the internal string that represents the display.
     */
    private void updateDisplay()
    {
        displayString = hours.getDisplayValue() + ":" + 
        minutes.getDisplayValue();
    }

    /**
     * Set alarm for clock
     */
    private void setAlarm(int phour, int pminute, int psecond)
    {
        aHours = phour;
        aMinutes = pminute;
        aSeconds = psecond;
        isSet = true;
        System.out.println("Alarm is set");
    }

    /**
     * Cancel alarm for clock
     */
    private void cancelAlarm()
    {
        isSet = false;
        System.out.println("Alarm is off");
    }

    /**
     * Check alarm for clock
     */
    private void checkAlarm()
    {
        if(aHours == hours && aMinutes == minutes && aSeconds == seconds)
        {
            System.out.println("Alarm is off");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is where the error is:

```
if(aHours == hours && aMinutes == minutes && aSeconds == seconds)
        {
            System.out.println("Alarm is off");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Where is the NumberDisplay class code?

Comment: the return type of `checkAlarm` is void, and you try to return a boolean

Comment: `aHours` is an int, and `hours` is a NumberDisplay.  You can't do an `if(aHours == hours...)` comparison, because you can't compare an int to a NumberDisplay.  Likewise for `aMinutes` and `aSeconds`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you have:

```
private NumberDisplay hours; // a variable called "hours" that is of type NumberDisplay
private NumberDisplay minutes; // a variable called "minutes" that is of type NumberDisplay
private NumberDisplay seconds; // a variable called "seconds" that is of type NumberDisplay
private int aHours; // a variable called "aHours" that is of type int
private int aMinutes; // a variable called "aMinutes" that is of type int
private int aSeconds; // a variable called "aSeconds" that is of type int
```

for `aHours == hours && aMinutes == minutes && aSeconds == seconds` to work, "hours" must be an `int` or unboxable into an `int` like `Integer`. Same for minutes and seconds.

What you want is to get the int value stored by each of these:

if (aHours == hours.getValue() && aMinutes == minutes.getValue() && aSeconds == seconds.getValue()) {

As you can see in the

```
public void timeTick()
{
    minutes.increment();
    if(minutes.getValue() == 0) {  // it just rolled over!
        hours.increment();
    }
    updateDisplay();
}
```

method that `minutes` has a `.getValue()` method that returns an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems with the code you posted.

To answer your question, though, you get the error because you are trying to compare an `int` with a `NumberDisplay` to see if they are equal.

In java, you can't do that. You instead would need to do one of the following:

a) convert the `int` to a `NumberDisplay`, and then compare them using NumberDisplay.equals() (but you may have to write that method yourself - try researching "overriding Equals in java")

b) convert the `NumberDisplay` to an `int`, and then compare them using the `==` operator that you're currently using. How you would convert to an `int` depends on what your `NumberDisplay` code does.

c) Write a method that knows how to compare a `NumberDisplay` to an `int`, and use that. Exactly how this would work, depends on what the code for `NumberDisplay` looks like, but generally you would create a method in `NumberDisplay` with a signature like this:

```
public boolean isTheSame(int compare)
```

---

As has been pointed out in comments, you also need to change your code so that any method that returns `true` or `false` has a "return type" of `boolean` instead of `void`

Comment: And if he changes `int` to a `NumberDisplay`, he also cannot use `==` then, because I assume he will try to.

Answer (score 0):

Two things need to be changed: function return type should be `boolean`.
You need to get the value of the NumberDisplay element. Since I don't have the code for NumberDisplay, I assume you can use `getValue` for it. This gives the following code:

```
    /**
     * Check alarm for clock
     */
    private boolean checkAlarm()
    {
        if(aHours == hours.getValue() && aMinutes == minutes.getValue() && aSeconds == seconds.getValue())
        {
            System.out.println("Alarm is off");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```